# Angular 2 nativeElement attribute testing in App component

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular 2 app I'm working on, which for some compatibility reasons with legacy code, needs to get some information via attributes used on the app component.  For example, the html that launches the angular 2 app would look like this:

```
<myApp id="xyz" areaDone="true" value="" requestID="abc"> Loading ... </myApp>
```

However, when I try to write some unit tests around the behavior that is supposed to occur based on the presence and value of these attributes, they are null/undefined.

To get the values, we are just pulling them in the constructor like this:

```
        let native = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        this.requestID= native.getAttribute("requestID");
```

So, is there a way through the testbed/providers to force a native element that should have the expected attributes?

Answer (score 8):

You can call `this.elementRef.nativeElement.attribute` and that will return a NamedNodeMap (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_attributes.asp) of your attributes.

Syntax for getting stuff from NamedNodeMaps isn't terrible, this is me getting the x1 attributes from a d3 object in one of my tests

```
const nodeAttributes = compiled.querySelector('#temp-draggable-link-line').attributes as NamedNodeMap;
expect(nodeAttributes.getNamedItem('x1').value).toEqual(200);
```

Comment: I understand that, as to how to see the attributes in the test, but what I need is to know how to set them on the source element.  As near as I can tell, the test harness just starts it up with a div tag with an id attribute, and I can't find any way to either inject a mocked ElementRef into the constructor or to set up the test runner to pass those attributes in to be read from the dom

Comment: Sorry, completely misunderstood your question. i just looked through the code and it looks like there are only four references to the function `insertRootElement` in @angular/core/testing. Where the function is defined, it only takes one parameter (the id) and where it is used, it calls that function then immediately calls the component factory. I don't think this is going to be possible unless you fork this or PR it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following syntax to get attribute value from html element

//to retrieve html element

```
const element = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('name of element'); // example a, h1, p
```

//get attribute value from that element

```
  const attributeValue = element.attributeName // like textContent/href
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how I could finally make it work

```
const element = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('name of element'); // example a, h1, p

const attributeValue = element['attribute name']; // for example src, href
```